# Error in ASP.NET jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I'm going to add a dialog in my web project and it works on the Index page.
But every time I try to go other pages, it always returns the following error:

> 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object does not support this property or method 'dialog'

How can I fix this error?

In my Layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Title</title>
<link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            height: 500,
            width: 650,
            show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
        });

        $("#modal-opener").click(function () {
            $("#dialog-modal").dialog("open");
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
```

...

```
<button id="modal-opener">Open Dialog</button>

<div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic model dialog">
    test
</div>
```

Comment: Can you give us an English error message?

Comment: `show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },` remove a trailing comma from here.

Comment: @jai i don't think it's cause of problem .

Comment: @pankajSharma well in the above code this is the only issue i see, so i suggested to remove it.

Comment: @Stijn, `JavaScript runtime error: Object does not support this property or method 'dialog'`.

Comment: thanks for the above suggestion, but i had try... not work for me ....!
or anyone else have a good suggest / guideline for me to add a dialog easily ! Thanks...!

Comment: but i had try no work....!

Comment: great...i found reason for my error 
it is because i place a @Html.Partial in the bottom of the pages...(i.e. it work proper when i remove the @Html.Partial)
i'm going to find the solution now....
any ppl have suggestion please.!?
thanks for everyone who had give me a help...